# can find open graph information about my fan page?

Tags: facebook

My fan page url is "http://www.facebook.com/sushiofsweden" and the id is "101982833243346"

but when I try to navigate to "https://graph.facebook.com/101982833243346" it returns "false"... why?

if I try to navigate to Starbucks open graph url "https://graph.facebook.com/22092443056" it return json string as expected.

so home come it doesn't work for sushiofsweden?

Comment: It works for me; http://graph.facebook.com/101982833243346 gives me http://pastebin.com/v7gdtQZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I visit http://www.facebook.com/sushiofsweden, I get redirected to http://www.facebook.com, so I believe it's because you haven't published your page yet.

edit: Now that you've published it, this works for me.

http://graph.facebook.com/101982833243346

```
{
   "id": "101982833243346",
   "name": "Sushi of Sweden",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276990_101982833243346_1291109588_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/sushiofsweden",
   "likes": 157,
   "category": "Local business",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.sushiofsweden.se/",
   "username": "sushiofsweden",
   "location": {
      "street": "Rapsgatan 1G",
      "city": "Uppsala",
      "country": "Sweden",
      "zip": "75450",
      "latitude": 59.8517609,
      "longitude": 17.6972599
   },
   "parking": {
      "street": 1,
      "lot": 1,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "general_info": "Sushi of Sweden etableras p\u00e5 utvalda platser och Uppsala, Bol\u00e4nderna \u00e4r f\u00f6rst ut.\nRestaurangen har en drive in med bike in som nytt inslag. Sommartid \u00e4r restau-\nrangen en gr\u00f6n oas med bambu och vegetation i volymhandelsomr\u00e5det Bol\u00e4nderna.\n\nEtt vilsamt pausrum mitt i vardagen f\u00f6r den som vill.\nDet \u00e4r enkelt att best\u00e4lla och h\u00e4mta sin mat hos Sushi of Sweden. Restaurangen\nhanterar heller inga kontanter med h\u00e4nsyn f\u00f6r milj\u00f6n och persons\u00e4kerheten.",
   "can_post": true,
   "checkins": 122,
   "talking_about_count": 35
}
```

Comment: Can you try again, I had a country restriction activated